# How to add entity multiple time to collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to have a relation for example `Job` with `Status`es as `many-to-many` where a job can have same status multiple time. How can i create this relation ship ?

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Status")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="jobs_statuses",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="job_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="status_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
protected $statuses;
```

In my case i have a `statuses` and i want to store at a `job` this statuses as a list, where the last one is a current one. And they can repeat. For example lets assume we have statuses: `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` where you can go multiple times to each status. And the list is like a history of statuses.

Comment: What's your problem precisely?

Comment: Updated question. Take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an history of statuses, you'll have to store an additional value, like a datetime. (If not, you don't have to keep multiple relations since they're all the same)

So, to have an history of statuses, you need to store the additional value (like a datetime), and therefore switch from a `ManyToMany` relation to two `OneToMany` relations, and an entity between them since a `ManyToMany` can't have extra column(s):

In the Job class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="JobStatusHistory")
 */
protected $jobStatusHistories;
```

In the new JobStatusHistory class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Job")
 */

protected $job;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Status")
 */
protected $Status;

protected $jobStatusDatetime
```

And finally in the Status class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="JobStatusHistory")
 */
protected $jobStatusHistories;
```